# can a dishwasher be installed 17 feet from sink?

Tags: kitchens, drain, dishwasher, installation

Due to the issues with my kitchen cabinet layout, I can't have my Bosch dishwasher installed next to the sink. The only place where the dishwasher can fit into is the cabinet that's 17 feet away from the sink, but Bosch said the drain hose can be extended up to 12 feet.

Is 17 ft too far in this case? How damaging it could be if the dishwasher is installed too far from the sink?

Comment: A dishwasher does **not** need to be next to a sink. But it needs access to water & sewer, and the easiest way is usually to put it next to a sink. Is there a cabinet next to the dishwasher that has space for plumbing **and** has reasonable access (either kitchen currently torn apart, or access from underneath) to be able to install plumbing there?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact The thing is the cabinets are quite new soI don't really want to tear them down, I mean otherwise wouldn't have this kind of frustration if I decide to get my cabinets replaced. There is space underneath the cabinets for plumbing, and my first thought was actually running a drain hose under the cabinets, but I'm not sure if it would work.

Comment: Can't run a drain hose anywhere near that length. But can put a trap in the next cabinet and then regular (e.g, pvc) pipes the rest of the way.

Comment: My dishwasher is a Klarstein and not plumbed in at all. The drain hose goes to a bucket which I empty into the sink. Two saucepans of water fill up the tank. It works for me.

Answer (score 14):

You can put the dishwasher wherever you want.

You will have to provide it with water and a drain that meets code - and it's not at all likely that you can run 17 feet to join the sink drain while meeting code. So you'll have to arrange plumbing to serve the water input and drain output needs of the dishwasher where you want to put it, independent of the sink.

Comment: An excellent case of looking at the real requirement.  The typical solution is to put the dishwasher next to the sink.  One reason is that water and drain are available.  Another is that it is nice to be able to load the dishwasher directly from the sink, but code doesn't care about that.

Comment: The primary limiter of a dishwasher will be the drain hose. It needs to drain properly or you'll get really nasty water in a couple weeks. If you have access to another ground drain then it is fine, if not, then that will be the limit.

Comment: Why not run 17 feet?  You need room to drop at least four inches over that run, but what's the issue otherwise?  A run that long would need a trap at the washer and additional venting, but you could use AAVs, I presume?  Two for that run, I think.